# Multiple tasks in the same node with SLURM

Tags: slurm

I'm struggling to understand how to run multiple processes in the same node using SLURM.

Suppose I want to run a program with 100 different input arguments. This is what I would do on my laptop for example:

```
for i in `seq 100`; do
  ./program ${i}
done
```

Now I have access to a cluster with 24-core nodes. So, I want to run 24 instances of the program on 5 nodes (24 on 4 nodes + 4 on a 5th node) at the same time.

I thought the submit script should look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 5
#SBATCH -n 100
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=24
for i in `seq 100`; do
  srun ./program ${i} &
done
wait
```

It turns out that, with this submit script, `./program` is run multiple times for every `i` value, even though `srun` is called only once for each loop.

What is going on? What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

By default, `srun` will use the full allocation in runs in, so here, the full 100 tasks. To tell is only to use a single core, you need to run

```
srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 ...
```

From the [srun manpage](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html):

> This option can also be used when initiating more than one job step
>   within an existing resource allocation, where you want separate
>   processors to be dedicated to each job step. If sufficient processors
>   are not available to initiate the job step, it will be deferred. This
>   can be thought of as providing a mechanism for resource management to
>   the job within it's allocation.

Comment: Thanks Damien! I guess my misunderstanding comes from the confusion among job vs. job step vs. task and node vs. processor vs. CPU.  Does the `--exclusive` option makes a node or a processor or a CPU exclusive to a task or a job or a job step?

Comment: No, in this context, it has no relation with that meaning.

Comment: Hmm.. Let me paraphrase. What if I don't add `--exclusive` to the command? Like this: `srun --ntasks 1 ./program $i`?

Answer (score 0):

Add `--nodes 1` will get rid of the warnings.

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 5
#SBATCH -n 100
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=24
for i in `seq 100`; do
  srun --exclusive --nodes 1 --ntasks 1 ./program ${i} &
done
wait
```